# How to export 1 action that contains two rig's animation

Tags: animation, rigging, nla-editor, actions

I have been told to export only one action containing the animations of the two seperate rigged pigs seen in the image. What is the best way to go about this? I have heard the suggestion of combining the rigs to a super rig, but this might throw off my skin weights, and ruin the current animations, and no guarantee I can make it work.I have also heard of unlocking object modes, but this also seems to be confusing to work with. Any suggestions will be welcome. Thanks

[image]